# Sharepoint Configuration. Server website access denied

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I finished configuring Share Point 2013 through the wizard on a Windows Server 2012 on a Virtual Machine.

Now when I click the server name from

"System Settings" -> "Manage servers in this farm" -> "Servers in Farm" -> Server Name,

I got a blank webpage with words:

```
Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.
```

I assume this is some access permission issue, do I have to edit the permissions of users?  What causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Run IE as an administrator.